# How would I delete a specific post id?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Sorry for my mistakes I'm fairly new to posting in stack overflow. Hopefully I provided enough info. In theory, I'm trying to press Cancel which deletes the row(got that part down) and deletes the corresponding id(-KiN...).

When I click cancel on the first record in the table it deletes the first record in the database but if I clicked the last record it still deletes the first record. So in short I'm having trouble canceling a reservation corresponding to the cancel button in the table.

https://jsfiddle.net/1s1h67u1/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy0uK.png

```
    var resvbTabRef = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user")
resvbTabRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  var specialKey = snapshot.key;
  var fullName = snapshot.val().Name;
  var phnNum = snapshot.val().Phone_Number;
  var ResvUID = snapshot.val().uid;
  var ResvDate = snapshot.val().Reservation_Date;
  var NumPeopl = snapshot.val().Number_of_Guests;
  var ResvEmail = snapshot.val().Email;

  var ResvInfo = fullName + phnNum + ResvDate + NumPeopl + ResvUID + ResvEmail

  if (user.uid == ResvUID) {
    var resvData = ('<tr><td ="' + specialKey + '">' + specialKey + '</td><td>' + fullName + '</td><td>' + user.email + '</td><td>' + phnNum + '</td><td>' + ResvDate + '</td><td>' + NumPeopl + '</td><td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-key=' + ResvInfo.key + ' id="cancelResv"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel</button>' + '</td></tr>')
    $("#userResvTable").append(resvData);

  } else {
    console.log("error");
  }


$('#userResvTable').on('click', 'button[type="button"]', function(snapshot) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    var resvbTabRef = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user/")
    resvbTabRef.once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

          var key = childSnapshot.key;
          var childData = childSnapshot.val();
          var ref = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user/" + key)
          return ref.remove().then(function() {
            console.log('OK, gone');
            console.log(childData)
          }).catch(function(e) {
            console.log('OOPS, problem:' + e.message);

          })

          childSnapshot.ref.remove();
          //                                console.log(resTab)
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve my problem by recreating the table. Finding the cell where the post key is positioned in first cell that corresponded to the cancel button that is clicked. After finding that cell I assigned it a variable and called that variable in .child(x) instead of key. I would like to thank Climb Tree for helping out.

```
var resvbTabRef = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user")
    resvbTabRef.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var specialKey = snapshot.key;
        var fullName = snapshot.val().Name;
        var phnNum = snapshot.val().Phone_Number;
        var ResvUID = snapshot.val().uid;
        var ResvDate = snapshot.val().Reservation_Date;
        var NumPeopl = snapshot.val().Number_of_Guests;
        var ResvEmail = snapshot.val().Email;
        var btn = "<button id='cancel' class='cancel'>Cancel</button>"
        var ResvInfo = fullName + phnNum + ResvDate + NumPeopl + ResvUID + ResvEmail
            //Only show users reservations if it equals their uid
        if (user.uid == ResvUID) {
            var table = document.getElementById("tablebody-reservation");
            var i = 1;
            //Grab snapshot of firebase     
            createTable();
            // console.log(document.getElementById("tablebody-reservation").rows[0].cells.item(0).textContent);
            function createTable() {
                var resvbTabRef = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user/");
                resvbTabRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {

                    var row = table.insertRow(0);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                    var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                    var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                    var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

                    cell1.innerHTML = specialKey;
                    cell1.className = "UID";
                    cell2.innerHTML = fullName;
                    cell2.className = "FullName";
                    cell3.innerHTML = ResvEmail;
                    cell3.className = "Email";
                    cell4.innerHTML = phnNum;
                    cell4.className = "Phone";
                    cell5.innerHTML = ResvDate;
                    cell5.className = "Date";
                    cell6.innerHTML = NumPeopl;
                    cell6.className = "People";
                    cell7.innerHTML = btn;

                    var a = document.getElementsByClassName('cancel');
                    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
                        a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                            var b = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[0].textContent;
                            console.log(b);
                            CancelButton(b);
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
            function CancelButton(b) {
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                console.log(specialKey)
                var resvbTabRef = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user/")
                resvbTabRef.once("value")
                    .then(function(snapshot) {
                        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot, uid) {
                            var key = childSnapshot.key;
                            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                            var ref = firebase.database().ref("Reservation/user/").child(b);
                            console.log(ref)
                            return ref.remove().then(function() {
                                console.log('OK, gone');
                                console.log(childData);
                                location.reload();
                            }).catch(function(e) {
                                console.log('OOPS, problem:' + e.message);
                            })
                        })
                    })
            }
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a sample how to do this. Just set onclick function of javascript on the button you'll show in each row. set onclick to some function and then pass a variable in that function. `<button onclick="deleteUserRow(uid)">Cancel</button>` now come to the javascript part. Add that function

```
deleteUserRow(uid){
  firebase.database().ref('Reservation/user').child(uid).remove();
}
```

Comment: Does this work for you please mention down in the comments?

Comment: But there is no uid in reservation/user. Reservation/user contains the push keys of me pushing reservations to the database.

Comment: In the above code uid refers to the id which we'll pass in function deleteUserRow. In other words uid is variable being passed to function you can rename uid to anything you want